# метод toString в классе BigDecimal

Tags: java

Листинг из JDK 1.8:

```
public String toString() {
    String sc = stringCache;
    if (sc == null)
        stringCache = sc = layoutChars(true);
    return sc;
}
```

Для чего нужна локальная переменная sc ? она не гарантирует ничего при многопоточном выполнении метода, я никак не могу понять её предназначение. Почему нельзя просто было реализовать метод так:

```
public String toString() {
    if (stringCache == null)
        stringCache = layoutChars(true);
    return stringCache;
}
```

Comment: Как раз sc, в данном случае, для каждого потока будет своя

Comment: @user287120 класс BigDecimal является Immutable (неизменяемым), возвращаемое значение String тоже

Comment: В данном случае метод возвращает не глобальную статическую ссылку, а отдельную для каждого потока, хоть и ссылаются они на ту же строку. Видать автор кода предохраняется от нестандартного использования метода toString(), результат которого некие умельцы могут использовать в бизнеслогике;)

Comment: @user287120 я не понял Ваш пример уязвимости и решения с помощью переменной sc

Comment: скорее всего микрооптимизация ([1](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-May/004165.html), [2](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-January/007708.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/))

Comment: @zRrr вынесите, пожалуйста, Ваш комментарий в ответ